# Create and printing formatted files in Java

Tags: text-formatting

I have this problem:
- reading data from a table or an array of textfields (they can be string type)
- from them composing a temporary text in order to print it on a printer(no record of the file)
- formatting and alignment are important.
Formatting in textareas doesn't work: for ex. String.format("%1$-20s %2$10s",string1,string2) in multiple lines. 
What can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps to clean the strings before attempting to format them using `printf`:

1. [Remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) all the line-breaks like this: `string1.replace("\n", "")`
2. [Trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) all leading and trailing white-spaces like this: `string1.trim()`